# Associating an alias with .org files on the Desktop

Tags: unity, emacs, alias

I have the following alias in my `.bashrc` on 16.04 LTS:

```
alias emacs-org='emacs -q --load ~/.emacs.d/init.org.el'
```

I would like to associate `emacs-org` with the `.org` files that I put on the desktop. I created a file called `emacs-org.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=GNU Emacs 24 Org
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=View and edit org files
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-org;
Exec=emacs-org
TryExec=emacs-org
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/emacs24.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
```

Still, the option `emacs-org` is not offered in the "Open With" menu. How do get `emacs-org` to show there?

Comment: your alias will not be expanded in a `.desktop` file - it's not going to be running in an interactive shell. You need to use the full command and full path (tilde `~` expansion will not work either)

Comment: @Zanna I put `emacs -q --load /home/meir/.emacs.d/init.org.el` for both `Exec` and `TryExec` with no effect (I did log out and back in. I do not need to reboot, do I?)

Comment: nah you don't need to reboot. I don't use emacs so I don't know what your command is trying to do exactly... sometimes you need to call bash, set some env like DISPLAY to get it to work. Hope someone can fix for you

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: No, I did not...